# Using Espresso to Run UI Tests, How do you reference the Close Icon in a Material Design Chip Layout?

Tags: android, material-design, material-ui, android-espresso

Typically if we wanted to press a button using espresso you would wait for the view with ID to be loaded. Then Perform click. Material design chip lets you define a close icon and place a listener on the close Icon. However, this means the closeIcon doesn't have an ID to reference directly and shows up as part of the Chip during layout inspector.

```
onView(withId(R.id.chip)).perform(click())
```

How would you use espresso to find the close Icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No easy way to do it with an espresso expression but after fiddling with it, it seemed Material Chip exposes a performCloseIconClick() function that I ultimately plugged into a Custom View Action. Hope this helps a few of you.

```
 class ClickCloseIconAction : ViewAction {

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(Chip::class.java)
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return "click drawable "
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        val chip = view as Chip//we matched
        chip.performCloseIconClick()
    }
}
```

This means you can call it like so

```
onView(withId(R.id.chip)).perform(ClickCloseIconAction())
```